# SPARQL Query filter location by label

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm new to SPARQL and need a query to get all businesses that are located in a specific city (property 'headquarters location').
The location should be passed as String such as "New York City".

I'm currently only able to query all businesses specific to one city (entity-based). My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?website ?location WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/(wdt:P279*)) ?item_s_0Statement.
  ?item_s_0Statement (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q4830453.
  ?item p:P159 ?location.
  ?location ps:P159 wd:Q60.
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P856 ?website. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en, de". }
}
```

This example returns all business located in Q60 (New York City).
Expected is that the query takes only "New York City" as String, so that it is easily replaceable.

Comment: You mean like this: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?website ?location WHERE {
  ?item (p:P31/(wdt:P279*)) ?item_s_0Statement.
  ?item_s_0Statement (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q4830453.
  ?item p:P159 ?location.
  ?location ps:P159 ?place .
  ?place rdfs:label "New York City"@en .
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P856 ?website. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en, de". }
}` ?

Comment: One comment regarding this query: This obviously will need for knowing the **exact label** in advance. And if there are places that have the same label, you're lost. By the way, that's the reason why entities in RDF are identified by URIs. Anything beyond the lookup by the exact label match needs for some kind of string matching via `regex` or similar.

Comment: @AKSW how would you suggest writing it with a regex instead of just referencing the label?

Comment: I would not suggest it, I just said that some regex or other kind of string function might help to some extent compared to having the exact label. I don't know your use/case, but imagine the input is "new york city" - that wouldn't match the label because everything is case-sensitive. Here some normalization like making the label and the input string lower case could help. For example `VALUES ?inputStr {"HERE_YOUR_INPUT_STRING"} ?place rdfs:label ?label filter(lcase(str(?label)) = lcase(?inputStr))` - I think you get the idea